# How can I make parameterized method?

Tags: java

I have similar class for making Product factory:

```
package com.nda.generics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import com.nda.generics.Sizeable.Size;

public class ProductFactory{

        private Collection<? extends Sizeable> sources;

        public ProductFactory(Collection<? extends Sizeable> sources) {
            this.sources=sources;
        }

        public void setSources(Collection<? extends Sizeable> sources) {
            this.sources=sources;
        }

        public Collection<Product> makeProductList() {

            Collection<Product> products=new ArrayList<Product>();

            for (Sizeable item:sources) {

                switch(item.getSize()) {

                    case BIG: products.add(new Sausage()); break;
                    case MIDDLE: products.add(new Feets()); break;
                    case LITTLE: products.add(new Conservative()); break;
                }
            }

            return products;
        }

        public class Conservative extends Product {

            private Conservative(){}
        }

        public class Feets extends Product {

            private Feets(){}
        }

        public class Sausage extends Product {

            private Sausage(){}
        }
    }
```

This factory makes list of products using size of animals. But I also need to parameterize method/class that I will set type of product, for exampe new Feets (using parameters of constructor). How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: I feel like I can help you but I don't understand your question. I don't see the Parameters  of your constructors. If you know them in advance then you can simply pass them from your factory. If you don't know the parameter in advance you must have something at runtime telling you which type it is by passing a Class<T> argument.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for....

```
public <T extends Product> T getNewProduct(Class<T> productClass, String param1, int param2) {

   T product = productClass.newInstance();

   // Assuming your abstract Product class defines these setters
   product.setStringParam(param1);
   product.setIntParam(param2);

   return product;
 }
```

And then you can call like this....

```
// Assuming you want a Feet object....
Feet feet = productFactoryInstance.getNewProduct(Feet.class, "productParam1", productParam2);
```

Also, as a side note, you should make your ProductFacotry a singleton.  You don't need more than one and it avoids a lot of other head aches, you can to this like so....

```
// Make ProductFacotry constructor private so you don't call "new" all over the place
private ProductFactory() {}

// Variable to hold your only instance of product factory (hence, singleton name...)
private static ProductFactory INSTANCE = null;

public static synchronized Get() {
  if(INSTANCE == null) {
    // You can call the constructor here, even though its private since you're
    // inside the same class
    INSTANCE = new ProductFactory();
  }

  return INSTANCE;
}
```

And then, whenever you want to use it to get a product, just do this....

```
Feet feet = ProductFactory.Get().getNewProduct(Feet.class, "productParam1", productParam2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a method you can say that it takes a unknwn number of String parameters.

The Feed constructor may be something like this:

```
public class Feets extends Product {
    private Feets(String... args){
    }
}
```

The argument 'args' will be an array of String's.